# Lightning Button is not working in salesforce1 app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, lightning-community

Component :

```
    <aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" controller="Quote_Preview_LE">
    <style>
      .forceChatterLightComponent .bodyWrapper{height:0%;width:0%;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
      .slds-modal__close{height:0%;width:0;padding:0;display:none;}
     </style>
     <aura:attribute name="ProfileId" type="String"/>
     <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.CheckPreview}" value="{!this}" />
    <aura:attribute name="quo" type="Quote__c" default="{'sobjectType': 'Quote__c'}" />
</aura:component>
```

controller :

```
({
    CheckPreview : function(component, event, helper){
            var qid=component.get("v.recordId");   
            //alert(qid);
            var action = component.get("c.getquoteid");
            action.setParams({ "recordId" : qid });          
            action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            parent.location.href =parent.location.href; 
            window.open("/apex/QuotePreview?id="+qid,"_blank");    
        });
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire()
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

quote preview is a pdf page. It is opening in classic and lightning desktop.

Answer (score 1):

This knowledge article [Open a PDF with Salesforce for Android and iOS app](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000268447&language=en_US&type=1) says:

> **Opening Dynamically Generated PDFs**
>
> If you're trying to dynamically
>   build and display your PDF file, you will want to generate and save
>   this file via your controller then navigate to the new ID accordingly.
>   Generating and saving it on the server side, will eliminate conflicts
>   noticed with the webview incorrectly handling content types across
>   different platforms, or other rendering related issues that may occur.
>   With this approach and navigating to the file directly, it should
>   provide a more consistent user experience in our supported mobile
>   environments.
>
> NOTE: Salesforce Support cannot offer assistance in building out the
>   functionality to dynamically generate PDFs, but we are able to assist
>   if there is a specific error observed when attempting to render the
>   dynamically generated PDFs.

plus using the `e.force:navigateToSObject` event to open the PDF.